# javascript how to switch pathname of window.location property and redirect

Tags: javascript, regex, window.location

I want to redirect a user from varying urls to a specific one.  I've tried various flavors of replacing and I cant seem to get the behavior I want.  This code works except I'm providing the hostname.  I want to use the existing hostname from windows.location.hostname and just provide a new pathname.  Sometimes the urls vary in size and slashes ('/').

```
window.location = 'http://localhost:36065/NewPath';
```

How would I change these urls?

```
http://somesite.com/xxx/yyy/zzz to http://somesite.com/NewPath
http://somesite.com/xxx/yyy to http://somesite.com/NewPath
http://somesite.com/xxx to http://somesite.com/NewPath
```

I think you get the point. The path can vary in paths, I want to replace everything after .com basically with 'NewPath'

I'd like a clean regex solution if possible but I am quite the rookie in that dept. Thanks for any tips or tricks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
location.pathname = '/newpath.html'
```

Comment: Also a note, this keeps the hash in the URL, but that's probably not a problem.

Comment: Not quite sure how I missed this. So simple. Thanks!

Comment: @vsync, By setting the `pathname` property you maintain query params and fragment identifiers.

Comment: @JasonHarwig - just tried changing the pathname and it **didn't** maintain query params.. (FF30/WIN7)

Comment: is there a way to change the pathname so that the browser doesn't "load" the new pathname?  I know there is `pushState()` but i'm trying to effectively remove the most recent url from the browser history and `pushState()` doesn't do this.

Comment: @user1063287 I believe the [`History.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) method would help here.

Answer (score 4):

You could always use [the various `location` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) to recreate the part you need and append the new part to it:

```
window.location = location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname + "/NewPath";
```

Comment: Indeed. I could add it, but I think @JasonHarwig has the best solution.

Comment: This is missing the port and possibly the hash and the search fields. `Location.origin` might help here.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show the hard way:

```
// Find everything up to the first slash and save it in a backreference
regexp = /(\w+:\/\/[^\/]+)\/.*/;

// Replace the href with the backreference and the new uri
newurl = windows.location.href.replace(regexp, "$1/dir/foo/bar/newpage.html");
```